# pip not pointed to anaconda after its installation

Tags: anaconda, conda

After installed anaconda,

`which pip` returns `~/anaconda2/bin/pip`

But both `pip --version` and `~/anaconda2/bin/pip --version` returns `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`. And running `pip install` or related commands are actually run pip from the one from system (e.g. /usr/local...).

This only happens to one machine that I have. On other machines, it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that PYTHONPATH is set by default in that machine to the system python path. By deleting this variable or direct it to conda's site-packages would solve the problem.

Comment: how can one do that?